# What is the Taylor series of $\sqrt{z}$ around $z=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

How do I calculate the Taylor series of $\sqrt{z}$ around $z=-1$ in the branch that implies $\sqrt{-1}=+i$ ?

I didn't find an answer in the web.

Comment: You can use the fact that with your choice of the branch, $\sqrt{z}=i\sqrt{-z}$.

Comment: @Yagel Minor note here — it should be *'Taylor series'*, not *'Tylor series'*. When you put the correct term back into Google, you might get more results.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any Taylor series.

$$(\sqrt z)'=\frac1{2\sqrt z},$$
$$(z^{1/2})^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!}{2^n}z^{1/2-n},$$

Then

$$\sqrt{-1}=i,$$
$$\frac1{2\sqrt{-1}}=-\frac i2,$$ $$\cdots\\$$
$$((-1)^{1/2})^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!}{2^n}(-1)^{1/2-n}=-i\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!}{2^n}.$$

For coherence, $(-1)^{1/2}=i$ everywhere.